# Unable to setup, Let's Encrypt

Tags: lets-encrypt, easy-engine

I’m trying install SSL to my EasyEngine serve, but the message bellow appears:

```
root@mautic:~# ee site update mautic.agencialoud.com --letsencrypt
Letsencrypt is currently in beta phase. 
Do you wish to enable SSl now for mautic.agencialoud.com?
Type "y" to continue [n]:y
Please Wait while we fetch SSL Certificate for your site.
It may take time depending upon network.
Unable to setup, Let's Encrypt
Please make sure that your site is pointed to 
same server on which you are running Let's Encrypt Client 
 to allow it to verify the site automatically.
```

I also looked for solutions in many places, followed several suggestions but without any success

I created two A records into my zone editor to point the EasyEngine app as subdomain (mautic) as we can see

A RECORDS:

```
mautic.agencialoud.com.     14400   IN  A   159.203.176.69
www.mautic.agencialoud.com.     14400   IN  A   159.203.176.69
```

Both of records are already pointing to server IP (159.203.176.69) as we can see in this link: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/mautic.agencialoud.com

Someone has any other suggestion to me?

PS: I don't have CloudFlare or any other kind of service like these

Answer (score 0):

set allow https port (443) in security group.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a CNAME record helped me solve the same issue.

```
CNAME   www.subodmain.domain.com  is an alias of subodmain.domain.com   43200
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same issue.
Resolved by using [CertBot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

1. Choose your OS and webserver
2. Install certbot
3. Run smth like `$ sudo certbot --nginx` and follow instructions
4. After that cert should be installed.

Somehow, you may check it by running `ee site update mautic.agencialoud.com --letsencrypt`